# Before delete trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can you use before and after in the same trigger?
I'm trying to see if the population is > 700000  when combining city population with country if so create a new table and add the total population to the new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't do that.

Slightly longer answer: The trigger's timing clause specifies when the trigger code will be executed, relative to the triggering event. If you were able to specify both **`BEFORE`** and **`AFTER`**, you would effectively be saying to run the trigger twice, performing the same action both times, which really doesn't make sense. Typically you would want to perform *different* actions before and after, which requires two different triggers.

Incidentally, using a trigger to create a new table usually doesn't make much sense either. What is it you're trying to accomplish?